# Parse error when reading csv file with two or more delimiters are present

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample Data**

```
354;monojet_Zp2000.0_DM_50.0;2.44336e-05;832841;-1.22431;b,947383,824498,-0.523103,1.64421;j,258722,243675,0.328962,2.25014;j,520092,108590,-2.2473,-1.85679;j,383024,88405.6,2.14516,-1.95635;j,39507.6,35365.1,0.47046,-1.16445;j,225430,26878.2,-2.81608,-2.25938;
354;monojet_Zp2000.0_DM_50.0;2.44336e-05;
```

**This is my test code:**

```
df=pd.read_csv('monojet_Zp2000.0_DM_50.0_chan3.csv',
              sep=';|,',
              engine='python',
              header=None)
```

**When running I get this error:**

```
ParserError: Expected 262 fields in line 6, saw 273. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Comment: What do you expect us to do?  Your data isn't consistent.  You'll have to fix it.  Perhaps you should post a line of the data.

Comment: What does line 6 look like? The error message indicates that there are too many delimiters on this line. Is it possible that this csv contains text and that there are commas in this text that are mistaken for delimiters? You will have to do some investigation, here.
And clean up the mess in your csv, so that there is only one delimiter and it occurs only where it should.

Comment: A line of data is updated. @TimRoberts

Comment: Is that two lines of data?  If so, it's not valid CSV data and pandas can't read it.  You pre-process it to add on empty fields so the number of fields is constant, or you can read the CSV yourself into an array, and feed the array to pandas.